# How do I assign a KVM guest / virtual machine one of my public IPs?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I have a subset of /29 (5 usuable IPs). I currently have my host using 1 of those IPs.

I want to setup a KVM guest to be assigned one of the available IPs and be able to open ports / port forward to run services on these.

My network configuration is through netplan and I'm using virt-manager to manage the VMs.

First it is recommend that you create a bridge. You can do by editing your config file inside of `/etc/netplan/` I can find out what my physical network interface is by typing the command `ip a` and seeing in my case it's called, `enp3s0`

My bridged configuration is as follows. Filling in placeholder IPs.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
  # Bridge configuration
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp3s0]
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [x.x.x.202/29]
      macaddress: FA:0B:8A:E4:1C:C0
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: x.x.x.201
          metric: 100
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      dhcp6: false
  version: 2
```

After setting up this configuration, I type the command `netplan generate` to generate the configs, then `netplan try` to test. It looks good and works and I press ENTER to apply the config.

The bridge seems to be created, what is the next step?

Comment: Create a static bridge in the host and assign your host static IP to the bridge. Add the physical interface into that bridge. Then, use that bridge in the libvirt. Make sure it doesn't attempt to do anything except adding tap interfaces into the bridge.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I added some more information to try and describe where I am stuck. I created a bridge and want to verify if my configuration is correct.

How do you go about making libvirt using `br0` ?

Comment: You should also state what is your host provider and give a link to the documentation from your host provider on how to use additional addresses. Some host providers have special restrictions and settings that might require different configurations than what would be logical to do.

Comment: @A.B Thank you for your comment. I'm coloing at Joe's DC and was assigned x.x.x.x/29 with 5 usable IPs, they mentioned they currently don't have documentation available. Please let me know if I can provide with any more information!

Comment: If there's no documentation chances are things are supposed to work as usual and you can ignore my previous comment.